# Testing load balancers in linux environment

Tags: linux, algorithm, load

I'm still trying to do a project which relates to making a simulation tool for network load balancing (similar with Cisco's Packet Tracer) but to verify the efficiency of the algorithm of my network load balancer i need to test it in real servers with my setup. What linux servers do i have to install and configure that provides network load balancing with algorithms like Round Robin, Minimum Expected Delay, Least Connections. These are the algorithms i need to test on my future setup.

note: and I'm talking about software load balancers.

Comment: Are you asking about things like LVS (Linux Virtual Server)?

Comment: Yes, I've done research and came across with that. Is it actually a load balancer that can be run on linux like ubuntu? I've also encountered HAProxy which is really common here and I think it has few algorithms that I want to test out but not all. For beginners how do I set up a server in linux? Is there any server distributions on linux like on windows? (e.g. windows server 2003) What are things that I need to install to setup server? (Or can I just install the software load balancer directly?) Thanks for those who will try to help. :)